# Why is the water steaming hot when it comes out of the tap on a coach/bus?

Tags: engine

I’m trying to work out how the tap on top of the toilet/in the toilet in a coach works? It’s on a toilet half way down the coach, and the tap water literally steams hot when it comes out. My friends and my question is: why is it so hot? We thought it was because the water needed to be boiled to get rid of bacteria, but also it could have been because it passes through the engine, or even because the sun outside has heated the storage tank. We’ve been giving theories for the last half hour but need an explanation! I hope this can be answered. If somebody has a diagram of this or can explain, this would be much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Sam

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure if you're asking why you are getting hot water into the toilet (which is *really* strange, in and of itself) or wondering what the method of getting the water hot in the first place is? If you could, update your question with the year/make/model/engine of the coach you're talking about, as well as additional clarification so we can provide you with a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each manufacturer can have a different method:

1) electric heater

2) waste heat from exhaust

But controlloing the max temperature is a sensible option...